# How to replace a text in RichTextBox that contains also an image - WPF

Tags: wpf, image, text, replace, richtextbox

> I'm using the following method to replace text in a rtf text.

```
            rtBox = new Lazy<RichTextBox>();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtfTextToBeReplaced));
            TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtBox.Value.Document.ContentStart, rtBox.Value.Document.ContentEnd);
            tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);

            string rtf;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                tr.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                rtf = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            rtf = rtf.Replace("a", "B");
```

> The result is :

{\rtf1\Bnsi\Bnsicpg1252\uc1\htmButsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fchBrset0 Times New RomBn;}{\f2\fchBrset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pBrd\plBin\ltrpBr\itBp0{\lBng1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch B}\li0\ri0\sB0\sb0\fi0\ql\pBr}
}
}

Is possible to replace just the text  and not the tags from richtextBox but keeping the images when the richtextBox contains text AND images?

If I used

```
                tr.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rtfTextToBeReplaced)), DataFormats.Rtf);
                temp = tr.Text.Trim();
                temp = temp.Replace("a", "B");
```

then it's replaced just the richText with text and not richText with images and Text.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to replace text in the `RichTextBox` containing images is not to parse the ***raw data***, but analyzing `inlines` and taking to account the possible text formatting.

After data is loaded to the `RichTextBox` control use the following method to replace all occurrences of the specified text by a new text:

```cs
public void ReplaceText(RichTextBox rtb, string prevText, string newText)
{
    TextPointer start = rtb.Document.ContentStart;
    while (true)
    {
        var searchRange = new TextRange(start, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange foundRange = searchRange.FindTextInRange(prevText);
        if (foundRange == null) break;

        foundRange.Text = newText;
        start = foundRange.End; // Continue the searching 
    }
}  

public static class RichTextBoxParser
{
    public static TextRange FindTextInRange(this TextRange searchRange, string searchText)
    {
        TextRange result = null;
        int offset = searchRange.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (offset >= 0)
        {
            var start = searchRange.Start.GetTextPositionAtOffset(offset);
            result = new TextRange(start, start.GetTextPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static TextPointer GetTextPositionAtOffset(this TextPointer position, int offset)
    {
        for (TextPointer current = position; current != null; current = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
        {
            position = current;
            var adjacent = position.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            var context = position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            switch (context)
            {
                case TextPointerContext.Text:
                    int count = position.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    if (offset <= count)
                    {
                        return position.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
                    }
                    offset -= count;
                    break;
                case TextPointerContext.ElementStart:
                    if (adjacent is InlineUIContainer)
                        offset--;
                    break;
                case TextPointerContext.ElementEnd:
                    if (adjacent is Paragraph)
                        offset -= 2;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```